# How to verify the Site Collection quota size?

Tags: quota, 2007, wss-3.0, storage, administration

One of the site-collection administrators wants to verify the Site Collection quota size (he does not have access to Central Administration.)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [SPSite.Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.usage.aspx) property which returns a [UsageInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.usageinfo.aspx) object. This object contains information such as storage. Or you can go to the top-level site of the site collection and choose Site Settings > Usage Summary.

Answer (score 1):

have them go to Site Actions, Site Settings, Storage Space Allocation (Under the Site Collection Adminstration Group). This shows Space Used and Space Remaining in the allocated quota.